# Adding Java to Boot2Docker Linux VM?

Tags: java, linux, docker, boot2docker, alpine-linux

I have images which are based on Alpine Linux with only JRE, and I'd like to be able to debug some through the host machine on Boot2Docker's Tiny Core Linux VM. Is this possible, or is there a better way, besides adding JDK right into the container? I'm having trouble finding out how to get Java working in this

Comment: OpenJDK has alpine... https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/

Comment: Debug a Java app which runs in Docker container? It'll be hard...

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to install Java in the boot2docker VM. You can attach a remote debugger running on your host directly to the JVM running in your docker container. You'll need to bind the container port to the boot2docker VM (for example: `docker run -p 4000:4000 myimage:latest`), then connect your debugger to the exposed port on the VM (e.g. 192.168.99.100:4000).